# Archive for CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I've created a CPT & used the default category & tags instead of creating new taxonomy for those CPT.

Now while generating the 'list all'/ archive page, my query is returning only the posts that added through the default posts> section of admin menu.

What if I want them separately? Should I use independent page templates with custom query?

Answer (score 0):

Custom post types are not included in the ordinary archives by default, even if registered with the `taxonomies` argument. You will need to add the post type to the query yourself.

```
add_action(
  'pre_get_posts',
  function($qry) {
    if ($qry->is_main_query() && $qry->is_category()) {
      $qry->set('post_type',array('post','yourposttype'));
    }   
  }
);
```